# AWS EventBridge Event Bus: Can't add scheduler Expression to custom event bus

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, event-bus, aws-event-bridge, bus

i need to add dynamically schedule expression rule to AWS EventBridge when the default event bus is full i create new event bus and start adding new rules to newly created event bus everything's works perfectly the problem is that the custom event bus don't accept schedule expression rule:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutRule operation: ScheduleExpression is supported only on the default event bus.
```

how can i overcome the situation please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only create scheduled rules using the default event bus. There's no means to create them on the custom bus https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html